# Why can't I change the __metaclass__ attribute of a class?

Tags: python, metaclass

I have a weird and unusual use case for metaclasses where I'd like to change the `__metaclass__` of a base class after it's been defined so that its subclasses will automatically use the new `__metaclass__`.  But that oddly doesn't work:

```
class MetaBase(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs["y"] = attrs["x"] + 1
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaBase
    x = 5

print (Foo.x, Foo.y) # prints (5, 6) as expected

class MetaSub(MetaBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs["x"] = 11
        return MetaBase.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

Foo.__metaclass__ = MetaSub

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

print(Bar.x, Bar.y) # prints (5, 6) instead of (11, 12)
```

What I'm doing may very well be unwise/unsupported/undefined, but I can't for the life of me figure out how the old metaclass is being invoked, and I'd like to least understand how that's possible.

**EDIT:** Based on a suggestion made by `jsbueno`, I replaced the line `Foo.__metaclass__ = MetaSub` with the following line, which did exactly what I wanted:

```
Foo = type.__new__(MetaSub, "Foo", Foo.__bases__, dict(Foo.__dict__))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metaclass information for a class is used at the moment it is created (either parsed as a class block, or dynamically, with a explicit call to the metaclass). It can't be changed because the metaclass usually does make changes at class creation time - the created class type is the metaclasse. Its `__metaclass__` attribute is irrelevant once it is created.

However, it is possible to create a copy of a given class, and have the copy bear a different metclass than the original class.

On your example, if instead of doing:

`Foo.__metaclass__ = MetaSub`

you do:

`Foo = Metasub("Foo", Foo.__bases__, dict(Foo.__dict__))`

You will achieve what you intended. The new `Foo` is for all effects equal its predecessor, but with a different metaclass.

However, previously existing instances of `Foo` won't be considered an instance of the new `Foo` - if you need that, you better create the `Foo` copy with a different name instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that didn't do exactly what I wanted, since I still want subclasses of `Foo` to have the metaclass, but I've edited my question to include the solution that did what I needed, based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `__metaclass__` attribute is not used when inherited, contrary to what you might expect. The 'old' metaclass isn't called either for `Bar`. The docs say the following about how the metaclass is found:

> The appropriate metaclass is determined by the following precedence
>   rules:
>
> - If dict['__metaclass__'] exists, it is used.
> - **Otherwise, if there is at least one base class, its metaclass is used (this looks for a __class__ attribute first and if not found,
>     uses its type).**
> - Otherwise, if a global variable named __metaclass__ exists, it is used.
> - Otherwise, the old-style, classic metaclass (types.ClassType) is used.

So what is actually used as metaclass in your `Bar` class is found in the parent's `__class__` attribute and not in the parent's `__metaclass__` attribute.

More information can be found on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149846/customary-to-inherit-metaclasses-from-type).

Answer (score 1):

Subclasses use the *__metaclass__* of their parent.

The solution to your use-case is to program the parent's *__metaclass__* so that it will have different behaviors for the parent than for its subclasses.  Perhaps have it inspect the class dictionary for a class variable and implement different behaviors depending on its value 
 (this is the technique *type* uses to control whether or not instances are given a dictionary depending on the whether or not *__slots__* is defined).

Comment: In my actual example, the parent class is from a third-party module, and I want to extend a class from that module, but have my own metaclass which overrides some of the behavior of the third-party module's metaclass.  Otherwise I'd definitely do what you suggest.

Comment: @EliCourtwright Perhaps you can roll your own class that delegates to the third-party module rather than inheriting from it.  That should give you full control over the class creation process while maximizing code re-use.